# How can I get the drop down option from the Property file- Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

- Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**. The Reports generating in the **TestNG** frame work.
- Currently writing script for a web application. It contains many drop downs and each drop down contain many options.
- I have the Property file (In the form of Login.txt file). In that i have stored my user id password and url then will get String `uid=p.getProperty("loginUsername");` like this.
- The scenario is in the same way it need to find the element through ID of the drop down then it need to get option from the text file to select in the drop down.
- Please suggest me is there any possibility to work like this.

The HTML tag as follows:

```
<select id="periodId" name="period" style="display: none;">
<option value="l4w">Last 4 Weeks</option>
<option value="l52w">Last 52 Weeks</option>
<option value="daterange">Date Range</option>
<option value="weekrange">Week Range</option>
<option selected="" value="monthrange">Month Range</option>
<option value="yeartodate">Year To Date</option>
</select>
```

How can i give these values in the text file as well as selenium webdriver code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have property file: then you can do like

1. enter property

periodId = Last 52 Weeks

and use

```
WebElement periodId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath expression"));
String periodIdvalue =p.getProperty("periodId ");
periodId.sendKeys(periodIdvalue );
```

In this way you can select value from dropdown using properties.

or you can use

```
dropdown.selectByValue(periodIdvalue);
```

Instead of sendkeys

Answer (score 2):

You can something akin to the following code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
// To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");
// or
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
// or
dropdown.selectByValue("prog");
```

(as taken from [here](http://sumitbit2005.blogspot.in/2014/01/working-with-dropdown-using-selenium.html))

Comment: I guess OP wants to retrieve values from properties file in order to select values.

Comment: I tried with all the above methods still can't able to select the drop down values :( when using **Karna's** method i'm getting error as **Cannot locate option with value: Last 52 Weeks** and when tried **Sumitbit2005** getting the error as follows **Cannot find elements with a null id attribute**. Can anyone help me to fix this issue..

Comment: please see my another answer it is working: I have used dropdown.selectByVisibleText("value"); instead of dropdown.selectByValue("");

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get dropdown id from properties file and find element  
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown.id")));
// Make a Select object using element
Select select = new Select(element);  
// Get option from properties file and use it
select.selectByVisibleText(p.getProperty("dropdown.option"));
```

In properties you can store it like
`dropdown.option=Last 52 Weeks`
or
`dropdown.option=Week Range`

Comment: Please any one suggest me the solution

Comment: @Amir: What else you are looking for? If I understood your question correctly, you want get dropdown option from properties file and want to use it. Right?

Comment: yes exactly. how you will show that in the property file.Is the normal html format i need to store

Comment: @Amir: You dont need to store HTML in properties file. I have updated my answer

Comment: The same way can i give all values in the text file. How can i call a particular option to select from property file

Comment: @Amir: Check my updated answer. Give a try and let me know if you face any issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47395/discussion-between-amir-and-karna)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with my above answer: I am getting error " Cannot locate option with value: Last 52 Weeks" so I have used

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText(period);
```

and it works successfully.

Below are my steps:

1. I have application.properties file to list the properties:

   PeriodId=Last 52 Weeks
2. ReadProperty.java file which read value from application.properties:

   package com.util;

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class ReadProperty
   {                       
           public String readApplicationFile(String key)
           {           
               String path =  this.getPath();  
               System.out.println(path);
               String value = "";
               try{                
                     Properties prop = new Properties();
                     File f = new File(path + "//src//com//util//application.properties");
                     System.out.println(f.getPath());
                     if(f.exists())
                     {
                         prop.load(new FileInputStream(f));
                         value = prop.getProperty(key);  
                   }
              }
               catch(Exception e)
               {  
                  System.out.println("Failed to read from application.properties file.");  
               }
               return value;
            }      
           public String getPath()
           {
               String path ="";        
               File file = new File("");
               String absolutePathOfFirstFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
               path = absolutePathOfFirstFile.replaceAll("\\\\+", "/");        
               return path;
           }   

     }
   ```
3. My code to select the value:

> ```
> package com;
>
> import org.openqa.selenium.By;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
> import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>
> import com.util.ReadProperty;
>
>
> public class NewTest4 {
>   protected WebDriver driver;
>   ReadProperty readpr = new ReadProperty();  
>
>   @Test
>   public void testfile() throws Exception
>   {
>     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
>     driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Sumit.Mittal/Desktop/ff.html");
>     String period = readpr.readApplicationFile("PeriodId");
>     System.out.println("the value is" + period);
>     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='periodId']"));
>     Select dropdown = new Select(element);
>     //dropdown.selectByValue(period);
>     dropdown.selectByVisibleText(period);
>
>
>   }
>   public void killDriver()
>   {
>   driver.close();  
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

try this it will work.